# How can I make a POST request with my payload with Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

In my project, I am taking values, from user inputs, which are then dispatched to redux and saved in an array.

However I'm trying to also use a PUT request to send/sync these input logs to a database AFTER the logic has been implemented in the Redux reducer.

I understand it is not best practice to send a fetch/POST request inside the redux reducer, so where can I send the new payload after it's been updated in the reducer?

Here is my component where users enter the data:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { logActions } from '../../store';
import classes from './AddLogModal.module.css';

const AddLogModal = () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [attention, setAttention] = useState(false);
    const [tech, setTech] = useState('');
    const techs = useSelector(state => state.tech.techs);
    const date = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const submitHandler = () => {
        let data = {
            message: message,
            attention: attention, 
            tech: tech,
            date: date,
        }

        dispatch(logActions.addLog(data));
        setMessage('');
        setAttention('');
        setTech('');
    }

  return (
    <div id='add-log-modal' className='modal'>
        <div className="modal-content">
            <h4>Enter System Log</h4>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field">
                    <input onChange={(e)=> setMessage(e.target.value)} type="text" name="message" value={message}/>
                    <label className="active" htmlFor="message">Log Message</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field">
                    <select className="browser-default" onChange={(e)=> setTech(e.target.value)} name="tech" value={tech}>
                    <option value="" disabled>Select a Technician</option>   
                    {techs.map(tech => (
                    <option value={tech.firstName} key={tech.id}>{tech.firstName} {tech.lastName}</option>
                    ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row">
                <div className="input-field">
                    <p>
                    <label>
                    <input 
                    type="checkbox" 
                    className="" 
                    checked={attention} 
                    value={attention}
                    onChange={()=> setAttention(attention => !attention)}
                    />
                    <span>Needs Attention</span>
                    </label>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" className="modal-close waves-effect waves-green blue btn" onClick={submitHandler}>Enter</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddLogModal;
```

Here is my redux store, where the data is being pushed to an array with logSlice

```
import { createSlice, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialLogState = {logs:[]};

const logSlice = createSlice({
    name:'log',
    initialState: initialLogState,
    reducers: {
        addLog(state, action){
            state.logs.push(action.payload);
            // console.log('log added');
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2));
        },
        removeLog(state, action){
            state.logs = state.logs.filter(log => log.id !== action.payload);
        },
        replaceLogs(state, action){
            state.logs = action.payload;
        }, 
    }
});

const initialTechState = {techs: []};

const techSlice = (createSlice({
    name: 'tech', 
    initialState: initialTechState,
    reducers: {
        addTech(state, action){
            state.techs.push(action.payload);
        }, 
        removeTech(state, action){
            state.techs = state.techs.filter(tech => tech.id !== action.payload);
        },
        replaceTechs(state, action){
            state.techs = action.payload;
        }
    }
}));

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        log: logSlice.reducer,
        tech: techSlice.reducer
    }
});

export const logActions = logSlice.actions;
export const techActions = techSlice.actions;
export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

So to communicate with database using API, You can use createAsyncThunk. After successfully updating the database, redux store should be updated but you are thinking opposite now.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk